# How does class objects created as program starts up in iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c

> Your class objects are created for you automatically as your program starts up, but instances must be created deliberately as the program runs.

[This book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch05.html) simple cover it. I confuse about how dose class objects created automatically as program start up. Somebody can describe this progress in detail?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to? singletons?

Comment: The class objects created if you are allocated memory for the class objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of his books *Matt Neuburg* himself explained this object creation sequence. Let me try to explain that in a simple manner.

> Class is a blueprint for your run time objects. Basically when you run your application, as soon as it load into the memory; the run time environment creates an object, a physical memory equivalent to the Class blueprint for each class. This is called a **Factory Object**. Remember that this factory object doesn't give permission to access the *ivar* but it allows to access to method definitions (that's how all instance shares the same definition/memory for a class). This *factory object* is also called *Class Object*.
>
> Because of this only you are able to call *alloc* method for a class at the first place, as a "sort of object" exist to call a method for that class. Once this *factory object* creation is done run time environment is ready to let you create instance objects by calling *alloc* or *new*.

I hope this is useful.

**EDIT: - Adding Book Link**

Check the explanation under **Class Methods** section on this page. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch02.html#_class_methods

Comment: Thank you very much! Will you mind tell me the book's name?

Comment: I don't remember now exactly under which version of iOS (iOS5, iOS6 or iOS7) programming books he mentioned that.