# Can someone please explain this to me - "Objective-C Classes Are also Objects"

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can someone please explain to me how a class can be referred as an object as mentioned in one of the apple docs pages as "Objective-C Classes Are also Objects"

Here is the link for the same :
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html

Comment: What the documentation was meant to say is that Objective-C runtime provides special objects of type `Class` that represent *metadata* about the class.

Comment: Check is this clears your doubt - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878781/how-does-class-objects-created-as-program-starts-up-in-ios-app/26929941#26929941](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878781/how-does-class-objects-created-as-program-starts-up-in-ios-app/26929941#26929941)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - it is more than just the metadata. Classes can also receive message  (I.e. You can invoke class methods such as `arrayWithArray`)

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C class objects participates in two important techniques:

- You can have a reference to a class object. In a class method `self` always refers to the class object.
- Class objects can receive messages.

This is useful, when you do not know the class at compile time. I. e.:

```
Class aClass = …; // I. e.: Rectangle, Circle, … selected by the user
Shape aShape = [[aClass alloc] init]; // Create a shape
```

Moreover it is useful for dynamic dispatching of class methods. Having:

```
@interface Shape : NSObject
…
@end

@interface Rectangle : Shape
…
@end

…

@implementation Rectangle
+ (NSUInteger)numberOfAnchorPoints
{
  return 2;
}
@end

@implementatin Shape
+ (void)doSomething
{
  NSUInteger = [self numberOfAnchorPoints]; // NOT: [Shape numberOfAnchorPoints]
  …
}
@end
```

Having a dynamic class object like:

```
Class shape = [Rectangle class];
[shape doSomething];
```

`+doSomething` of the subclass `Rectangle` is executed, even `Shape` does not even know of its subclasses.

Or, to have a more simple example:

```
@implementation NSObject
+ (id)new
{
  return [[self alloc] init]; // self points to the receiver, not to NSObject
}
@end

…

Custom* custom = [Custom new]; // The receiver is the class object of Custom.
```